# How to display the result using a barchart

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have used boolean to select row that are more than 400. I am required to display the result in a `barchart` using `Matplotlib` but encountered this error message `"TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars"`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df2 = pd.read_csv("1.csv",index_col='month')
df3 = df2[df2.total > 400]
print(df3)

df = np.genfromtxt("1.csv", skip_header=1, dtype=[('month','U10'),  ('total','f8')], delimiter=",",
missing_values=['na','-'],filling_values=[0])

labels = list(set(df['month']))
levels = np.arange(0,len(labels))
levels_values = df[['month','total']]
total_amt = levels_values['total']

total_amount = {}

for i in labels:
    valuesforlevel = total[levels_values['month']==i]
    m = df1    
    total_amount[i] = m  

plt.figure(1, figsize=(50,30))
barchart = plt.bar(list(total_amount.keys()), list(total_amount.values()), color='teal')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Which line exactly gives the error?  Unfortunately, your post is missing reproducible test data. Can you add the start of the output of `total_amount.keys()` and `total_amount.values()`.

Comment: What is the meaning of `m = df1; total_amount[i] = m`?  Note that `df1` is undefined here.  If it is a dataframe, assigning it to `total_amount[i]` looks extremely suspicious. Maybe you meant `total_amount[i] = valuesforlevel`?